# event.currentTarget toggle class of chield element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to toggle a class of chield element of the `element.currentTarget` and its not working. I don't know what to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="post-footer-icons-container-el" data-btntype="comment">
    <div class="post-footer-icons-circle bluei">
        <img class="post-footer-icons"src="/icons/chat-bubble.png"> 
    </div>
      UserPosts[i].retweetedpost.numComments %> 
 </div>
```

JS:

```
event.currentTarget.children(".post-footer-icons-circle").removeClass("redl");
```

I don't mind if I use this class or not, I just want to select the first and unique child and toggle the class.

All code:

```
$(".post-footer-icons-container-el").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const postid = event.currentTarget.parentElement.getAttribute("data-postId");
    const typebtn = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-btntype");
    
    if(typebtn==="like"){
        //no funciona async await en jquery .on
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/useractions/likepostmanage",{
                "likedpost":postid
            }).then(function(response){
                //the parent event handler will not be triggered
                
        });

        event.currentTarget.children(".post-footer-icons-circle").toggleClass("redl"):
    }
    if(typebtn==="rt"){
        //no funciona async await en jquery .on
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/useractions/retweetpostmanage",{
                "retweetedpost":postid
            }).then(function(response){
                //the parent event handler will not be triggered
                
        });
        $(event.currentTarget).find(":selected").toggleClass("redl");
    }
    
    event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

Anything is working for me for work with childs.

Also above code gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: event.currentTarget.children is not a function

Comment: please edit your summary of your issue, I don't even think. you finished your sentence of your question. but from what I see in your description the error is very clear 'Uncaught TypeError: event.currentTarget.children is not a function' you can use a debugger or console log event and then check to see if it has a currentTarget with children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery object `$(this)` and  call the first `.children()` using `eq`  to toggle your class.

Example:

```js
$(".post-footer-icons-container-el").on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).children(".post-footer-icons-circle:eq(0)").toggleClass("redl");
});
```

```css
.redl {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-footer-icons-container-el" data-btntype="comment">
  <div class="post-footer-icons-circle bluei">
    <img class="post-footer-icons" src="/icons/chat-bubble.png">
  </div>
  count
</div>
```